# Is it discouraged to use one-liner for-loops or if-statements in Go?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, go

For example, a simple check for an empty string:

```
if s == "" { return 0 }
```

Or, a for-loop to pre-fill an array with -1 (I don't think there's an easier way to do this):

```
for i := range m { m[i] = -1 }
```

Is this generally discouraged, even if these functions are extremely simple altogether? I don't mean to be pedantic, but am generally curious what the sentiment for this is.

Comment: Code conventions are somebody's preferences. Not necessary it always has some rationale behind it, what is important is that they are followed by everybody.

Comment: This is not gofmt'ed code. Nobody is interested in reading or discussing un-fmt'ed code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, the culture in Go is to format your code the way the command [`go fmt`](https://blog.golang.org/go-fmt-your-code) would format it. (The reasons why there is an accepted style are in the linked article.)

To the extent that `go fmt` puts structured statement bodies on separate lines means that yes, the practice is "discouraged" in the community, but only because of a desire to have a common look for as much Go source code as possible.

The reasons *why* one-liners are not part of `go fmt` are not as relevant as the fact that `go fmt` was chosen as the canonical style. If you wish to argue about the pros and cons of one-liners, you can look at the debates made in just about any curly-brace language, as they are not unique to Go. Of course, Go's mandating of braces does make the question slightly different than, say, C or Java, where unbraced bodies means it's harder to "add a new statement in the body," but basically many of the same arguments for readability do apply.